# Why Laravel do not works

Tags: php, laravel, macos, laravel-5

I've got a little problem, I can not run Laravel on my Mac OS X (the version of my Laravel is 5.4 PHP 7.3 and the error appears below.

```
(3/3) ErrorException
compact(): Undefined variable: operator (View: /Users/marques/Sites/barramento/resources/views/layouts/template.blade.php) (View: /Users/marques/Sites/barramento/resources/views/layouts/template.blade.php)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auur2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use that version of Laravel with PHP 7.3.

You have 3 options:

1. Upgrade Laravel (best option by far)
2. Downgrade PHP (not so good, security)
3. Tell composer to use an "untagged" version of `laravel/framework` for 5.4 where this has been fixed, but never released as a tagged version (since that version of Laravel is out of support)

[Laravel Github - Issues - [5.4] Fix Query Builder breakage with PHP 7.3](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26937#issuecomment-477546785)

Answer (score 1):

Undefined variable and the variable in "resources/views/layouts/template.blade.php",
maybe you get something from database and the database is empty or error in connection.